# How do I get a Lexmark T652 printer working?

Tags: printing

My system is Ubuntu 14.04. The printer is Lexmark T652.

In my institute, it need user name and passwd to printer document.

I added printer via "System Setting -- Printer" or cups. It no error during adding, but it did not come out with a dialog to input user name and passwd. So when I submitted printer job to printer, it always denied my printed job.  What'd wired, on the page of cups, it said "job completed".

Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was fixed by changing the username, which indicates some mysterious underlying issue unlikely to be reproducible (something to do with the institutional setup?)

Answer (score 0):

In command line input/type following command:

```
usermod -l new_user_name old_user_name
```

`new_user_name` is the user name requested by printer.
Also need to change the password.